# what will be the best way to calculate total ASCII value of the string of characters in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I was searching for this question on StackOverflow but didn't get any questions that are answering it. So I posted it here.

I want to calculate the ASCII value of the string which is only consisting of characters in a simple way as possible in SQL.

The string is "DESIGNATION OF EMPLOYEE". I want to calculate the total ASCII value of the string.

I tried the longest approach till now, which seems like this -

```
SELECT SUM(ASCII('D')+ASCII('E')+ASCII('S')+ASCII('I')+.....) AS "TOTAL ASCII" FROM  DUAL;
```

NOTE: I want to calculate the total ASCII value of the string which includes combined ASCII values of all the characters.

Comment: Please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS as the *sql tag* description suggests

Comment: This is not a task that SQL is made for. This is an iterative process (going from the first character to the last one where the length of the string is variable). You *can* do this with a recursive query in most RDBMS, but a programming language is better suited for the task.

Comment: You tagged Oracle's sql*plus. The Oracle DBMS comes with a built-in programming language: PL/SQL. I suggest you use this to write a function for the task. This is more readable than a SQL solution.

Comment: Fun fact: [ASCII()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions007.htm) does not necessarily return ASCII.

Comment: `ASCII` does not return the ASCII code number. It returns the decimal representation in the database character set - which nowadays is most like not `US7ASCII` anymore

Comment: I suggest you to read this document first: [Linguistic Sorting and Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch5lingsort.htm)

Comment: Maybe you are actually looking for this: [NLSSORT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions125.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using `DUMP()` function along with Regular expression functions such as

```sql
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT str0, REGEXP_SUBSTR(DUMP(str0),'[^: ]+$') AS str 
   FROM (SELECT 'DESIGNATION OF EMPLOYEE' AS str0 FROM dual)
)
 SELECT str0, SUM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'[^,]+',1,level)) AS "TOTAL ASCII"
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(str,',')+1
  GROUP BY str0
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46b1c2f6b271e95b9d5fdc9ef9adabf0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONNECT BY` to unfold the characters, then `SUM` the `ASCII` values.

> ```
> SELECT str
> , SUM(ASCII(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'.',1,level))) AS "TOTAL ASCII"
> FROM (SELECT 'DESIGNATION OF EMPLOYEE' AS str FROM DUAL)
> CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'.',1,level) IS NOT NULL
> GROUP BY str;
> ```

| STR | TOTAL ASCII |
| --- | --- |
| DESIGNATION OF EMPLOYEE | 1642 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=144ffe85f670ae22c1be70eeac723750)*

Comment: I'm curious, why do you even need something like this?

Comment: whenever I use the WHERE clause for characters, like WHERE Ename > 'smith', it returns an answer on the base of ASCII values. The character with greater ASCII value will only return but how to prove that fact? that's why I need to calculate the ASCII values.

Comment: The sorting doesn't depend on the total ascii value of the string though.  But by each character from left to right. F.e. the string 'B2' is greater than 'B10' because '2' comes after '1' in the ascii table.

Comment: @AMAN KAG: That makes no sense. First of all, the comparision is usually not done on ASCII values, but based on the session's region's lexigraphical order. Then, how on earth did you get the idea that the comparision was based on the *sum* of ASCII values???

Comment: I was taught by the wrong teacher about this wrong concept, that's why I wanted to recheck whether that really works, I was checking that and you answers my other question also, thank you guys now my all misconceptions are clear regarding it.

Comment: Btw, it may be important for a SQL expert to realise this. When someone complains about how the numbers are sorted wrong in his query, the first suspicion would be that the column isn't a number type.